# Using Ruby with GraphQL resolve issue of NameError: uninitialized constant UserMutations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

So I'm using GraphQL with Ruby on Rails and trying to get GraphiQL to work but I end up with NameError: uninitialized constant UserMutations. In my mutation_type.rb I have the following:

```
Types::MutationType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
 name 'Mutation'
 field :signUp, field: UserMutations::SignUp
 field :updateUser, field: UserMutations::Update
 field :changePassword, field: UserMutations::ChangePassword
 field :signIn, field: AuthMutations::SignIn
 field :removeToken, field: AuthMutations::RemoveToken
end
```

Then in my mutations folder for user_mutations.rb I have:

```
module Mutations::UserMutations
 SignUp = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
   name 'signUp'
   description 'Signing up a user'

   input_field :first_name, types.String
   input_field :last_name, types.String
   input_field :email, types.String
   input_field :password, types.String
   input_field :password_confirmation, types.String

   return_field :user, Types::UserType
   return_field :messages, types[FieldErrorType]

   resolve lambda(obj, inputs, ctx) do
     user = User.new(inputs.to_params)
     if user.save
       user.update_tracked_fields(ctx[:request])
       user.generate_access_token!
       { user: user }
     else
       { messages: user.fields_errors }
     end
   end
 end

 Update = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
   name 'updateUser'
   description 'Updating a user account'

   input_field :first_name, types.String
   input_field :last_name, types.String
   input_field :email, types.String

   return_field :user, Types::UserType
   return_field :messages, types[FieldErrorType]

   resolve lambda { |_obj, inputs, ctx|
     current_user = ctx[:current_user]
     if current_user.update(inputs.to_params)
       { user: current_user }
     else
       { messages: current_user.fields_errors }
     end
   }

 end

 ChangePassword = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
   name 'changePassword'
   description 'Changing the user password'

   input_field :password, types.String
   input_field :password_confirmation, types.String
   input_field :current_password, types.String

   return_field :user, Types::UserType
   return_field :messages, types[FieldErrorType]

   resolve lambda { |_obj, inputs, ctx|
     params_with_password = inputs.to_h.symbolize_keys
     current_user = ctx[:current_user]
     if current_user.update_with_password(params_with_password)
       { user: current_user }
     else
       { messages: current_user.fields_errors }
     end
   }
 end

end
```

Originally I had for the user_mutations.rb:

```
module UserMutations
 SignUp = GraphQL::Relay::Mutations.define do
```

But found out we're not using React but Vue. How do I correctly get my mutation_type file grab the info from the user_mutations file?

Edit:
I have also tried in my mutation_type file the following:

```
Types::MutationType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name 'Mutation'
  field :signUp, Mutations: UserMutations::SignUp.field
```

And

```
field :signUp, field: UserMutations::SignUp.field
```

Same issue with both.

Comment: You have a typo in your mutation_type file, the space in `Mutation: UserMutations` it should be `Mutations::UserMutations`

Answer (score 0):

I'm still wondering what does front-end `React` or `Vue` have to do with your backend.

You have an issue with the namespace, Rails is expecting to find a file name that match `user_mutations.rb` the error `NameError: uninitialized constant UserMutations` produced as it's failing to locate it, you just need to guide rails to the file location.

I'm using GraphQL as well and I'm following this namespace in this url: https://mattboldt.com/2019/01/07/rails-and-graphql/

either way try this:

```rb
field :signUp, field: Mutations::UserMutations::SignUp
```

OR

```rb
module Mutations
    class UserMutations # if it didn't work, try `< Types::MutationType`
        SignUp = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
            # your SignUp block
        end
    end
end
```

OR Both of the above.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was a side-effect, I rolled the server logs way up the hill and found a syntax error in one of my resolvers